# multiprocessing.Process and websocket - Connection Aborted Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, multiprocessing

I´m using the Python multiprocessing module to handle responses from a websocket.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    connection = connect.Connect()
    server_message = message.server_message(connection._ws)

    chat = messageHandler.MessageHandler(server_message)
```

This class opens the connection to the websocket, using connect.Connect():

```
class Connect:

    def __init__(self):
    self._ws = create_connection(config.server['ws-server'])
```

The class server_message handles the responses from the server

```
class server_message:

    def __init__(self, ws):
        self.ws = ws

    def recv_message(self):
        return self.ws.recv()
```

Now the piece of code producing the error is in the Message_Handler class, which is supposed to take the server response, identify the first bit of it and put it in a multiprocessing.Queue

```
class MessageHandler():

    def __init__(self, server_message):
        self.server_message = server_message
        self.processes = {}
        self.queues = {}

        while(True):
            received_message = self.server_message.recv_message()
            self.sort_message(received_message)
```

The problematic part is this function implementing multiprocessing.Process:

```
elif((queueName in self.queues) == False):

    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q.put(received_message)
    self.queues[queueName] = q

    p=multiprocessing.Process(target=self.empty_queue, args=(q,))
    self.processes[queueName] = p
    self.processes[queueName].start()
    print(self.processes[queueName])


def empty_queue(self, queue):
    print("went good until here")
```

If i start the Program, i get the following output:

```
<Process(Process-1, started)>
went good until here

connection aborted error win error 10053 an established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

The traceback looks like this

```
 File "C:/Users/Martin/PycharmProjects/ps-battle-bot/main.py", line 19, in <module>
 chat = messageHandler.MessageHandler(server_message)
 File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\ps-battle-bot\messageHandler.py", line 16, in    __init__
received_message=self.server_message.recv_message()
File "C:\Users\Martin\PycharmProjects\ps-battle-bot\message.py", line 8, in   recv_message
return self.ws.recv()
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\websocket\__init__.py", line 710, in recv
opcode, data = self.recv_data()
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\websocket\__init__.py", line 725, in recv_data
frame = self.recv_frame()
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\websocket\__init__.py", line 800, in recv_frame
self._frame_header = self._recv_strict(2)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\websocket\__init__.py", line 931, in _recv_strict
bytes = self._recv(shortage)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\websocket\__init__.py", line 913, in _recv
bytes = self.sock.recv(bufsize)
```

Judging from the error message it seems to be some kind of problem with the websocket, but i cant really figure it out.
Sorry for the heaps of code, but googling didn't help at all and the error message is very uninformative.
I´m on a Windows x64 with python 3.3.2

Comment: do you have anything against PEP8 or spaces?

Comment: could you put the entire runnable source in a Pastebin?  I'd like to try to get it working.